# Windows gvim with &shell set to Cygwin bash broken by Windows 10

Tags: cygwin

A recent upgrade appears to have broken the ability of Windows-native `gvim` (7.4) to run `:!`-like commands using Cygwin's `bash` as the shell. (No doubt it's something that's been configured for my convenience that I'll have to find and deconfigure.)

If you can tell me how I might fix it, work around it, or help things along, thank you, etc., etc.

## The minimal example

First, enter this list into the buffer of a new `gvim` window:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Then, configure the shell settings to Cygwin bash:

```
:let &shell="C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe"
:let &shellcmdflag="-c"
:let &shellxquote="\""
```

Finally, run `wc` using the shell, replacing the current buffer contents.

```
:%!/usr/bin/wc
```

On the Windows 10 machine, I get a few seconds of hang followed by an E485 at the bottom of the window:

```
shell returned 254

E485: Can't read file C:/Users/psmay/AppData/Local/Temp/VIo4283.tmp
```

The Windows 8.1 machine I have on remote, which is otherwise similarly configured, behaves appropriately, replacing the buffer with `wc`'s output:

```
 5  5 15
```

Comment: I've observed a similar issue since the last W10 update. My opinion is that you should report it to cygwin mailing list.

Comment: @shellter: I actually did some searching to inform my guess of which SE site to use for this question. Naturally, I guessed wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Short version: Switch to an x64 build of Vim.

After tracking down [some more recent Vim builds](https://tuxproject.de/projects/vim/), I found out that the latest 32-bit (x86) build fails the above test in the same way, but the 64-bit (x64) build succeeds. Incidentally, the `gvim` already on my machine is from the installer on [Vim's own download page](http://www.vim.org/download.php), which is evidently also a 32-bit build.

(Still no idea, though, why running 64-bit Cygwin from 32-bit Vim is suddenly illegal.)

Comment: I had similar problem. On cygwin mailing list I've found [a thread](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2015-04/msg00623.html) that made me look for another build of gvim. Since my migration (to this [version](https://bintray.com/veegee/generic/vim_x64)), I'm now able to run `system("ls")` again.